# How to view second hard drive with Windows 7 in Linux

Tags: linux

I have one PC with two disk drives. The first one has Win 7 Pro on it (sda1). The second drive has Linux CentOS 7 (sda). I want to be able to access everything in sda1 while I am running CentOS from sda. I tried mounting it, but I got the following error:

what I tried: mount /dev/sda1 /media/windrive

The error I got:
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs'

Comment: first, post the output of `lsblk -f` to make sure you got the correct drive. Your statements on `sda` and `sda1` make me doubt that you got the correct drive. **If** there is something installed on `/dev/sda` (unpartioned) then there **is no** `/dev/sda1`!

Comment: /dev/sda would be an unpartitioned raw device, and /dev/sda1 the first partition on the same physical drive, so what you're describing can't possibly be what you have.

Comment: lsblk -f shows sda name=(sda1,sda2) fstype=(ntfs,ntfs) label=(System,OSDisk), nothing under mountpoint. It also shows sdb name=(sdb1,sdb2) with fstype=(xfs, LVM2_member) with mountpoint /boot, [SWAP], /, and /home. Clearly sda1, sda2 refer to the Windows, and sdb1, sdb2 refer to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install the following required packages which Centos by default does not support ntfs (Make sure you have the rpmforge repo installed)

Install the following packages.

```
             yum install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g
```

If the rpmforge repo is disabled by default,

```
             yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g
```

create a mount point

```
         mkdir /mnt/nftsdrive
```

Next, edit /etc/fstab as follows.

To mount read-only:

```
         /dev/sde1 /mnt/ntfsdrive ntfs-3g ro,umask=0222,defaults 0 0
```

To mount read-write:

```
        /dev/sde1 /mnt/ntfsdrive ntfs-3g rw,umask=0000,defaults 0 0
```

You can now mount it by running:

```
        mount /mnt/nftsdrive
```

Comment: I got the following error: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'

Comment: try to see if ntfs module is loaded by `modprobe ntfs` command and also check if `rpm -qa ntfs*` was installed.

Comment: modprobe ntfs says FATAL: Module ntfs not found. rpm -qa ntfs* takes a while, but returns to the prompt without errors.

Comment: how about `modprobe fuse`, please make sure both patches install properly.

Comment: check this link http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/NTFS. if you are running CentOS 5.3 or older then you would need to install kmod-fuse.

Comment: modprobe fuse does not return any error. Just returns to the prompt. For some reason, after trying the above suggestion, when I reboot my CentOS7 does not boot to the desktop environment. It goes to emergency mode! I have to figure out what is going on. This whole Linux idea started out as being exciting, but has become a pain in the back to do the simplest things. I guess Linux is great is you are an expert already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Create a mount point:

```
mkdir /mnt/ntfs
```

Then try to mount:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/ntfs
```